# Not working ToolTip in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This code is not working in my **AngularJS** file:

```
angular.element('document').ready(function() { $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50}); });
```

But when i put an *alert* inside, it pops up the alert message. The ToolTip code is not working though I've included all the required materialize **CSS** and **js** files. It works fine when I use the same code for a static element, but not working with dynamic element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because angularjs rerenders the template so the DOM is not the same anymore and has no plugin attached to it. When using angulajs, jQuery plugins mostly won't work because of that, therefore you have to create a directive to allow angularjs to orchestrate the plugin initialization so it apply the plugin when you dynamically add the new element.

Try something like this:

```
app.directive('tooltipped', function (){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
             $(elem[0]).tooltip({delay: 50}); });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try for this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tooltip - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#age').tooltip({delay: 50});
});

  </script>
  <style>
  label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p><label for="age">Your age:</label><input id="age" title="We ask for your age only for statistical purposes."></p>
<p>Hover the field to see the tooltip.</p>


</body>
</html>
```